# Cannot produce external source map with webpack2

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-2, source-maps

I have an issue after migrating an Angular project from webpack1 to webpack2.
Everything works well except sourcemaps.
It embeds a sourcemap inside my JS files as a base64 encoded string.
It of course creates insanely big files.

I want to have separate map files in prod.
However, all my attempts to control the source map generation were unsuccessful.
I've tried to disable them with uglifyjs, I tried to disable them in the tsconfig.json and of course I played with the devtool parameter which is set to 'source-map'.
I've tried everything I could think of.
I also tried to change my typescript loader, with no result.

I have the impression that I have the same behavior as if I had chosen 'inline-source-map' instead of 'source-map'.

Here's my webpack config as well as my tsconfig and package.json

Thank you in advance for your help !

Webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
var CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
var UglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin');

var loginUrl = 'https://renaissance-authent.xxx.xx';//'http://localhost:52445';
var apiUrl = 'http://localhost:50519';
var clientSiteUrl = 'http://localhost:10123';

var isProd = (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'prod' || process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production');

if (isProd) {
    apiUrl = '/api';
    clientSiteUrl = 'https://renaissance-client.xxx.xx';
    loginUrl = 'https://renaissance-authent.xxx.xx';
}

const METADATA = {
    title: 'xxx',
    baseUrl: '/',
};

function isExternal(module) {
    var userRequest = module.userRequest;

    if (typeof userRequest !== 'string') {
        return false;
    }

    return userRequest.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
}

var plugins = new Array();

plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.API_URL': JSON.stringify(apiUrl),
    'process.env.CLIENTSITE_URL': JSON.stringify(clientSiteUrl),
    'process.env.LOGIN_URL': JSON.stringify(loginUrl)
}));

// Ignore moment locals other than English
plugins.push(new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/));

// Fixes errors with Angular
plugins.push(new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
  /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
  path.join(__dirname, 'app/')
));

if (isProd) {

    console.log('Production Configuration');

    // Split vendor code and app code
    plugins.push(new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        chunks: ['app'],
        minChunks: function (module) {
            return isExternal(module);
        }
    }));

    // MD5 hash on generated chunks
    plugins.push(new WebpackMd5Hash());

    // Minimize JS code
    plugins.push(new UglifyJsPlugin({
        beautify: false,
        sourceMap: true,
        output: {
          comments: false
        },
        mangle: {
          screw_ie8: true
        },
        compress: {
          screw_ie8: true,
          warnings: false,
          conditionals: true,
          unused: true,
          comparisons: true,
          sequences: true,
          dead_code: true,
          evaluate: true,
          if_return: true,
          join_vars: true,
          negate_iife: false
        },
    }));
}

// Provide jQuery as a global plugin
plugins.push(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery'
}));

// Move CSS to a separate file
plugins.push(new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].[chunkhash].css"));

// Generate the index.html
plugins.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './app/index.html',
    chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
}));

plugins.push(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: 'Web.config' },
    { from: 'Content/favicon.png', to: 'images/favicon.png' },
    { from: 'Content/AppleIcon_180_180.png', to: 'images/AppleIcon_180_180.png' }
]));

plugins.push(new WebpackNotifierPlugin());

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        app: './app/main.ts'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].map',
        publicPath: '/'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.css', '.scss'],
        alias: {
            highcharts$: "highcharts/highstock.src"
        }
    },

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    module: {
        rules: [
            /*
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    options: {
                        configFileName: 'tsconfig.json'
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: 'angular2-template-loader'
                }]
            },
            */
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader?minimize=false'
            },
            { 
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|ico)$/i, 
                loader: 'file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]' 
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/i,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader' })
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader!sass-loader' })
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: plugins
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf wwwroot/*",
    "build": "set NODE_ENV=production&& npm run clean && webpack -d --color --display-error-details",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 10124"
  },
  "keywords": [ ],
  "author": "",
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": { },
  "devDependencies": {

    "typescript": "2.1.4",
    "typings": "2.1.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",

    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2", 
    "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "4.0.2",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.3.1",

    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "lato-font": "2.0.0",

    "systemjs": "0.20.12",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.3.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5",

    "angular2-highcharts": "0.5.5",
    "mydatepicker": "1.9.7",

    "moment": "2.18.1",

    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "@types/filesaver": "0.0.30",

    "webpack": "2.4.1",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
    "ts-loader": "2.0.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "style-loader": "0.16.1",
    "sass-loader": "4.1.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "node-sass": "4.5.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.5.0"
  },
  "repository": { }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem.
I was passing the parameter -d to webpack.
This happen to force the source map behavior.

Switched to -p and it's much better. Of course.

I keep that in case it helps someone.
I was focusing so much on the config that I forgot the console arguments.